# Is it possible to complete a checkout in shopify for private app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I developed an app using react & node, and I reached the point where the user enters his credit card information, now all what is left is to call the shopify API to create a checkout using there `REST` admin API but I'am getting `"[API] This action requires merchant approval for write_checkouts scope."` although I update the permission to `Read and writ` any help is appreciated.